# Wifi network disabled

Tags: wireless, internet

[image]Iam using Ubuntu 20.4v on my Dell Inspiron laptop for the past 2 years. Everything was fine until 2 days ago, my wireless connectivity was disabled. I had used the wifi just a day before perfectly.
I am unable to enable the wifi, I googled & tried many ways to enable the wifi network thru' the terminal but failed.
On the contrary, when I plugged in a USB wifi receiver, I was able to see the available wifi networks & connect to my wifi.
Kindly help...

Regards
Bharath

Comment: Without knowing any details about your hardware, this will be very difficult to answer. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the Terminal output of `lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet|wireless|wi-fi` (1) the Terminal output of `sudo lshw -c network` (2) what might have happened two days ago to affect your network (updates, modifying files, etc.)

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: @matigo - I'm sorry, I'm unable to follow your instructions, I did not get any response in the terminal with the above mentioned command in the terminal. Pls help further

Comment: If the two Terminal commands returned nothing — not even an error — then you are not running Ubuntu 

Comment: @matigo - I did get a response only for the second command as mentioned by you.

Comment: @matigo - how do i attach the screen shot of the response in the coment section ??

Comment: Copy/Paste is usually better. Select the text, [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[C] to copy (unless you've changed the key combination, then [edit] your question to include that output 

Comment: @matigo - i have attached the pic for your ref, pls help further.

Comment: *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: c1
       serial: b8:ac:6f:5f:c6:fb
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation

Comment: configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:28 memory:f0400000-f043ffff ioport:2000(size=128)

Comment: Based on your screenshot (and comments), there is no WiFi device found by the OS. This can mean either the device has been disabled (a hardware switch?), removed, or broken. `sudo lspci` and/or `sudo lsusb` would let you know whether the device is seen at all but, if you are unable to get any results, then it will be difficult to offer next steps.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: @matigo - 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 12)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)

Comment: 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)

Comment: 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)

Comment: ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)

Comment: @matigo Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6461 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
The above response is for lsusb - i am currently using a TP Link USB wifi reciever

Answer (score 0):

Enable wireless via a function key on your keyboard.  On my Dell Inspiron the key combination to enable wireless is Fn+F2 and I can see a little wireless symbol printed on the F2 key.

I was having the same exact situation as you.  I must have toggled that key combination and forgot about it.  I see that when the Fn+F2 is toggled to 'disable' status, the KDE networks wireless interface is disabled and non-responsive.  In other words, the keyboard switch is the master switch relative to the KDE network interface.

Comment: i have tried that combination right in the begining & every other combination of keypad keys but in vain.

Comment: Rats.  Have you ran lspci yet in your terminal?  You might try it without the grep option.You should see an entry for 'Network Controller' which should describe your wireless adapter.